# what is the right way to query a 2dsphere index to get results sorted by nearest-first with max_distance?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

```
> version()
version: 2.0.4
can't find special index: 2d for: { location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 0.1, 0.1 ] } }, $maxDistance: 5000.0 } }
> version()
version: 2.0.4
can't find special index: 2d for: { location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 0.1, 0.1 ] } }, $maxDistance: 5000.0 } }
> db.syncsnapshotsphere.find()
{ "_id" : "naga", "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 0.1, 0.1 ] }, "timestamp" : 1375778757.568005 }
{ "_id" : "nagb", "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 0.2, 0.2 ] }, "timestamp" : 1375778792.552187 }
{ "_id" : "nagc", "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 0.3, 0.3 ] }, "timestamp" : 1375778803.047879 }
{ "_id" : "nagd", "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 0.4, 0.4 ] }, "timestamp" : 1375778814.088595 }
> db.syncsnapshotsphere.find({location: {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [0.1,0.1]}}, $maxDistance: 5000}})
error: {
    "$err" : "can't find special index: 2d for: { location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ 0.1, 0.1 ] } }, $maxDistance: 5000.0 } }",
    "code" : 13038
}
```

The weird looking "cant find special index..." soon after the second line "version..." is actually the output... I don't know why.

I am trying to figure out why I get the error saying that it is trying to find a 2d index where as a 2dsphere index already exists on the location field... All help is appreciated.

```
> db.syncsnapshotsphere.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "logging_stuff.syncsnapshotsphere",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "location" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "ns" : "logging_stuff.syncsnapshotsphere",
        "name" : "location_2dsphere",
        "background" : false,
        "dropDups" : false
    }
]
>
```

Comment: Can you please try `db.syncsnapshotsphere.find({location: {$near: {$geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [[0.1,0.1]]}}, $maxDistance: 5000}})`?

Comment: @randunel the double brackets did not help... copy-pasted your query... same error :(... But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2dsphere` is an index type introduced in MongoDB 2.4, and you are using 2.0.4. Because you're doing a geo query with 2.0.x, MongoDB expects a `2d` index. Please upgrade MongoDB to 2.4.x and this will work just fine.

Comment: I came across what you have just said, in the documentation for mongoengine... but then I fail to understand the existing 2dsphere index... Is it like the index exists in this version but querying with those operators is still not supported? and of course, then I shall just upgrade...

Comment: You can create any sort of index type: ``ensureIndex( { 'foo': 'boogiewoogie' } )`` works too, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: I didn't know it was like that. Thanks a lot!